# MS Access Query Designer - similar functionality using standard .NET 3.5 controls?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, forms, controls

I would like to achieve something very similar to Microsoft Access query designer - I am talking about a plane(canvas?)-like surface on which users can place and move controls. Is this even possible?

If it isn't possible with free .NET controls - then are there any paid ones, which offer similar functionality?

Comment: Could you provide more definition of your goal?  You apparently don't want to create a query designer, but how similar is the thing that you do want to create?

Comment: [ReportBuilder?](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9f783224-9871-4eea-b1d5-f3140a253db6&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything is possible if you try hard enough.

I would explore WPF, it will provide capabilities to custom build your own controls and will get rid of that tedious work of keeping the UI updated.

Make sure to follow a good UI pattern if you do end up working with WPF, here is a good video that explains how to [implement MVVM in WPF](http://community.infragistics.com/pixel8/media/p/91950.aspx).